# Why Lipscitz smoothness not always implies strong convexity of Fenchel conjugate?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, legendre-transformation

Can someone please clarify what is exact reason why $L$-Lipschitz continuity of gradient of convex function $f$ may not imply $1/L$-strong convexity of its Fenchel conjugate $f^*$ in the case when $f$ is defined on $S \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^d$? For example, if $f(x) = +\infty$ for all $x \notin S$.

Comment: If you assume that the conjugate is strongly convex, which contradicyion can you derive ?